# Constructing Monthly Snapshots of Time Stamped Data in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr

A little problem I'm faced with. Idealised example here:

I've got a dataframe that records the dates that changes were made to the `value` of an insurance policy. This would look something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(policy_no  = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                 date_stamp = as.Date(c("2020-01-15", "2020-04-03", "2020-05-31", "2020-07-22", "2020-01-05", "2020-03-17", "2020-06-04" )),
                 value      = c(1000, 2000, 3000, 2000, 500, 1000, 500))
```

I've got two policies, `policy_no` 1 and 2. For each of these I'd like to write a bit of code to tell me the status of the `value` item as of the 1st of every month. So my output would look like

```
df_output <- data.frame(policy_no =  c(rep(1, 8), rep(2, 8)),
                        as_at_date = c(seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 8), seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 8)),
                        value = c(NA, 1000, 1000, 1000, 2000, 3000, 3000, 2000, NA, 500, 500, 1000, 1000, 1000, 500, 500))
```

[image]

Obviously I could write a loop to do this (for each `policy_no`, for each `as_at_date`, give me the `value` for the most recent snapshot where the `date_stamp <= as_at_date`) but that'd be slow & clunky. Can I vectorise this somehow?

`tidyverse` based approaches are particularly welcome, but grateful for any suggestions regardless.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach. First, create a monthly date sequence for each policy. Then, `group_by` both the policy and monthly date, and filter only those monthly dates beyond the date stamp. Finally, use `slice` to take the last row of data, containing the most recent value. Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(policy_no) %>%
  mutate(as_at_date = list(seq(floor_date(min(date_stamp), unit = "month"), ceiling_date(max(date_stamp), unit = "month"), by = "month"))) %>%
  unnest(cols = as_at_date) %>%
  group_by(policy_no, as_at_date) %>%
  filter(as_at_date > date_stamp) %>%
  slice(tail(row_number(), 1))
```

If you want to include the `NA` for January, you can join with your date sequence, so all months will be included:

```
df_dates <- df %>%
  group_by(policy_no) %>%
  mutate(as_at_date = list(seq(floor_date(min(date_stamp), unit = "month"), ceiling_date(max(date_stamp), unit = "month"), by = "month"))) %>%
  unnest(cols = as_at_date) 

df_dates %>%
  group_by(policy_no, as_at_date) %>%
  filter(as_at_date > date_stamp) %>%
  slice(tail(row_number(), 1)) %>%
  right_join(df_dates %>% select(policy_no, as_at_date) %>% distinct()) %>%
  arrange(policy_no, as_at_date)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   policy_no, as_at_date [15]
   policy_no date_stamp value as_at_date
       <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <date>    
 1         1 NA            NA 2020-01-01
 2         1 2020-01-15  1000 2020-02-01
 3         1 2020-01-15  1000 2020-03-01
 4         1 2020-01-15  1000 2020-04-01
 5         1 2020-04-03  2000 2020-05-01
 6         1 2020-05-31  3000 2020-06-01
 7         1 2020-05-31  3000 2020-07-01
 8         1 2020-07-22  2000 2020-08-01
 9         2 NA            NA 2020-01-01
10         2 2020-01-05   500 2020-02-01
11         2 2020-01-05   500 2020-03-01
12         2 2020-03-17  1000 2020-04-01
13         2 2020-03-17  1000 2020-05-01
14         2 2020-03-17  1000 2020-06-01
15         2 2020-06-04   500 2020-07-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Updated the df sorting by policy and month
Please find the solution below:

```
df <- data.frame(policy_no  = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,1,1,1, 2, 2, 2,1,1,1),
                 date_stamp = as.Date(c("2020-01-15", "2020-04-03", "2020-05-31", "2020-07-22", "2020-01-05", "2020-03-17", "2020-06-04", "2020-01-05", "2020-03-17", "2020-06-04","2020-03-01","2020-02-01","2020-01-01","2020-03-01","2020-02-01","2020-01-01" )),
                 value      = c(1000, 2000, 3000, 2000, 500, 1000, 500,500, 1000, 500, 500, 1000, 500,500, 1000, 500))
df$date <- format(as.Date(df$date_stamp,format="%Y-%m-%d"), format = "%d")
df$month <- format(as.Date(df$date_stamp,format="%Y-%m-%d"), format = "%m")

df_temp <- df[df$date == "01",]
df_temp <- df_temp[order(df_temp$policy_no,df_temp$month),1:3]
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't seem to be giving me what I wanted.